# Facing Performance issue with JGit add command with big repository

Tags: jgit

My local repository already has more than 10,000 objects. I am seeing performance issues while using the `git.add()` command to add one more file to the index. Below is the JGit code snippet which I am using to interface my Java program with Git:

```java
String absoluteLocalGitPath = "c:\\localGitRepo\\.git"
FileRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
repositoryBuilder.setMustExist(true);
repositoryBuilder.setGitDir(new File(absoluteLocalGitPath));
repository = repositoryBuilder.build();
git = new Git(repository);

AddCommand addCommand = git.add();
addCommand.addFilepattern("folder1/obj10001.obj");
addCommand.call();
```

Here path passed in file pattern is the relative path to c://gitLocalRepo.

Comment: How is performance if you use the commandline `git add` command? Maybe you need to run the GC command from time to time to optimize storage of objects...

Comment: command line add command works fine. Calling GC doesn't make any difference. I did some profiling and found org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryInserter.int(int,long,inputStream)
org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator.getEntryContentLength()
org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.enterSubtree()  are expensive calls.